# Trouble connecting django (container on ec2) to a postgresql database (container) running on a remote server

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

**So here is the setup:**
1. I have a django container, postgresql container, and an nginx proxy running on an ec2 instance
2. I have another postgresql container running on locally on an ubuntu server
3. I am trying to connect the django server to the local postgresql server just to read data

**Configuration:**
1. for django I have the configuration for the remote database
2. Here is the config.  All variables are set in a .env file

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
    },
    'nlp_data': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': os.environ.get('NLP_DB_HOST'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('NLP_DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('NLP_DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('NLP_DB_PASS')
    }
}
```

**Problems:**
1. The postgresql container on my local server...  What would be the host of this database?  Is it the public IP of the ubuntu server? Not sure
2. Is there a better way to debug these network issues? I have been getting timeout errors (assuming this is because my django container is unable to reach my local db server)

I have tried using the public IP of my local ubuntu server but that did not solve anything or tell me anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall and/or container networking issue.  You should be able to connect from the django host to the postgres host, and you need to make sure the postgres host is forwarding postgres traffic to the container.

Since you didn't indicate how you're running the containers, I'll assume you're using docker on both. Also, since you didn't indicate what OS you're running on the ec2 instance, I'll assume linux.

Using docker, you can see that the postgres host is forwarding traffic like so:

```
postgres@postgres-host:~$ docker ps
```

And look for a line such as:

> 1234abcd5678 postgres:13.1 "docker-entrypoint.s…" 13 hours ago Up 4 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp             postgres-1

The `0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp` part indicates that the postgres host is forwarding port 5432 (postgres default) traffic on all interfaces to the container.

The other thing you should do is verify you can connect from your running django container to the postgres host.  You can use the postgres CLI tool to do that:

```
django@django-host:~$ docker exec -ti <django-container-name> psql -h <postgres-hostname> -U <username>
```

The tool will prompt you for a password.  You can also run the psql command from the django host.  You might need to install the postgres client to make this work.  If you're using ubuntu/debian you can do that with `sudo apt install postgresql-client`.

The host of the database *for an external client* will be the hostname/IP of the server that the container is running on.

If the psql command times out, then I suggest you look at the firewall settings of the postgres host server and make sure that the django container host can reach the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes I am using docker on both and the ec2 is linux.  the psql command times out.  I am going to play with the firewall settings and reply back with what I found.

Comment: So I am able to ping my local ubuntu server from the django container on EC2.  But, I am unable to run psql when I pass the host(times out).  On the local server I allowed tcp traffic from port 5432 with ufw. Still no luck.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What are your security group and/or network ACL settings on the EC2 instance?  You'll want to make sure port 5432/tcp is open to traffic from the django container host.

Comment: So I have 2 default rules some have some Mysql rules on port 3306.
I also have a custum rule with 1) Inbound SSH 2) Inbound HTTP 3) Inbound Postgresql (not sure if I need this because nothing is trying to reach port 5432 on this EC2 server 4) Outbound Postgresql with TCP protocol on port 5432.  I will check ACL I have not looked into that

Comment: You'll want a security group attached to the EC2 instance running postgres with inbound PostgreSQL (TCP/5432) open to the host running the django container.  Outbound is typically all traffic / all protocols / all ports to 0.0.0.0/0.  If you can't figure out what the IP of the django host is, you might try starting with 0.0.0.0/0 (all hosts) and see if you can get it working, assuming you're comfortable with that.

Comment: You'll also want a security group attached to the host running the django container that will allow the postgresql responses back from the server.  One easy way to do both, if the EC2 instances are all in the same VPC, is to create a security group with all inbound / outbound traffic allowed when the source is the security group itself, and attach that to both.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by forwarding my network traffic on port 5432 to my local ubuntu server